# Why isn't stl compare function a member?

Tags: c++, stl, comparison, name-decoration

Just idly curious why the compare function for stl::sort can't be a static member?

I have a small little helper class foo that is declared and defined in a header, but now I have to create a foo.cpp file for the implementation of cmp() so it isn't multiply defined.

I also have to think of a suitably decorated name so fooCmp() doesn't clash with any other cmp().

Because it has no access to any member variables any compare operation that needs access to some other value (eg. sort by distance from foo.bar) needs the complex bind2nd call.

Comment: Compare function for `std::sort` _can_ be a static member. Whatever your problem is, it's not there - show the code!

Comment: It would have helped if VC++, when you get one tiny thing wrong win STL, didn't produce an error message that looked like a cat walked across your keyboard and then ran the US tax code through the resulting perl script.

Comment: It's a curse of all C++ implementations, not just VC++ (though I hope they improve it a little bit in VC10 with `static_assert`). Concepts would help there, but alas they're dead in the water now...

Comment: +1, mgb. You, sir, are an internet hero.

Comment: "I have a small little helper class foo that is declared and defined in a header, but now I have to create a foo.cpp file for the implementation of cmp() so it isn't multiply defined" You know, you can define a class and include the body of the methods in the class definition. That way they will be automatically inlined if possible (which is probably desired for a comparator), and you don't have to worry about putting it in a separate file.

Comment: But I wasn't able to make cmp a member that was the problem. In fact it was a type in the definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what you are complaining about:

```
std::sort(begin,end)        // use operator<
std::sort(begin,end,order)  // Where order is a functor
```

So order can be:

- A function
- A static member function
- Or an object that behaves like a function.

The following works for me:

```
class X
{
    public: static bool diff(X const& lhs,X const& rhs) { return true;}
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<X>   a;

    std::sort(a.begin(),a.end(),&X::diff);
}
```

But if the class has some natural ordering then why not just define the operator< for the class. This will allow you the access to the members and will behave nicely for most of the standard containers/algorithms that need to define an ordering.

```
class X
{
    public: bool operator<(X const& rhs) const   {  return true;}
};
int main()
{
    std::vector<X>   a;

    std::sort(a.begin(),a.end());
}
```

Comment: Sorry had the defn slightly wrong - I thought I had remembered that you couldn't do this.

Comment: You should add "free function" to the list of arguments that can be passed into sort.  Also, using &X::diff is visually ambiguous with pointer to member.  I think it would be better to use "&(X::diff)" or to allow the function to pointer conversion to happen implicitly "X::diff".

Comment: @mgb:  The example you may be thinking of is where your predicate function is itself a template.  The problem there is that the predicate arguments are not automatically deduced and so you must explicitly specify them when you call std::sort.

Comment: @Richard. Are you stalking me :-) I though the list above included "free function" is that not the same as "A function" as apposed to "A Method" which you can not pass to sort.

Comment: @Martin:  No I'm not stalking you (at least not intentionally)!  Re my "free function" comment, hmmm - you're right I don't know now how I missed "function" in your list.

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned with a multiply defined compare function, try declaring the function with `static` linkage. Then the scope of the function does not extend past the compilation unit where it is found.

That said, your compare "function" need not be a function at all, but can instead be a function *object*. A function object is very much like a function but is implemented as an `operator()` that takes the appropriate parameters within a regular class. Since it's a regular class, you can pass constructor parameters to the class.

Here is a simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class comparator {
public:
    bool operator()(int a, int b) {
        return a < b;
    }
};

int main(int, char *[])
{
    vector<int> a;
    a.push_back(1);
    a.push_back(3);
    a.push_back(2);
    sort(a.begin(), a.end(), comparator());
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

actually sounds like the function was 
declared in the class,
defined in the header but outside the class without inline linkage

ie something like:

```
class foo{
public:
   static bool compare(const foo& lhs,const foo& rhs);
   ...
};
bool foo::compare(const foo& lhs,const foo& rhs){
   ...
}
```

instead of

```
class foo{
public:
   static bool compare(const foo& lhs,const foo& rhs);
   ...
};
inline bool foo::compare(const foo& lhs,const foo& rhs){
   ...
}
```

the first of which will cause the function to be defined in every compilation unit that

```
#includes "foo.h"
```